# Calculation of the input impedance of reactance modulator

Tags: impedance, reactance

[image]

The figure 1.36 is a circuit of reactance modulator which is equivalent to a tunable inductance. I know the input impedance expression is Zin = (Z1 + Z2)/(1 + gm*Z2), but how to derive this expression?

Comment: Go look up gyrators.

Answer (score 1):

Well $$Zin = \frac{Vx}{Ix} $$

where **Vx** is a input voltage and

$$ Ix = \frac{Vx}{Z1+Z2} + gm*v $$ 
additional 
\$ v =Vx*\frac{Z2}{Z1+Z2}\$

So we have this

$$ Ix = \frac{Vx}{Z1+Z2} + \frac{gm*Vx*Z2}{Z1+Z2} $$

$$ Ix = Vx(\frac{1}{Z1+Z2} + \frac{gm*Z2}{Z1+Z2}) $$

$$ Ix = Vx(\frac{1+gm*Z2}{Z1+Z2}) $$

And finally

$$ Zin = \frac{Vx}{Ix}=\frac{Z1+Z2}{1+gm*Z2} $$

Do you see now how we derive this expression?

Comment: Yes, I get it. So taking the current as a clue. Thank you!